# convert resultset to model in spring boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to use specified query to fetch data from database using `@Query` but I get this error

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [org.closure.gcp.models.UserQueryModel]] with root cause

How can I convert the result of this query to my model?

query method in my repository

```
@Query(value = "select u.name as name,c.college_name as college_name from users u inner join college c ON u.college_id = c.id GROUP BY name", nativeQuery = true)
   List<UserQueryModel> usersWithCollege();
```

model class

```
public class UserQueryModel {

    private String name;
    private String college_name;
    //getters setters
}
```

the result table in the database will be like this

```
+------+--------------+
| name | college_name |
+------+--------------+
| cpp  | CAE-DU       |
| cs   | IT-DU        |
| java | IT-DU        |
+------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to user Native query then you can do like.

**Covert Return type with List of Object** Like below,

```
@Query(value = "select u.name as name,c.college_name as college_name from users u inner join college c ON u.college_id = c.id GROUP BY name", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object> usersWithCollege();
```

Then after you can create Constructor in your model and covert List of Object into your Pojo like,

```
public List<UserQueryModel> convertToModel(List<Object> object) {
    List<UserQueryModel> list = new ArrayList<UserQueryModel>();        
    for(final Object o : object) {
        Object[] obj = (Object[]) o;
        list.add(new UserQueryModel(obj[0].toString(), obj[1].toString()));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Pankaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3595228/pankaj) has a right answer and I found this way to do it.

repo method

```
@Query(value = "select u.name as name,c.college_name as college_name from users u inner join college c ON u.college_id = c.id GROUP BY name", nativeQuery = true)
    List<List<String>> usersWithCollege();
```

service method

```
public List<UserQueryModel> queryUsersCollege()
    {
        List<List<String>> list = userRepo.usersWithCollege();
        return list.stream().map((mapper)->{
            return new UserQueryModel(mapper.get(0),mapper.get(1));
        }).toList();
    }
```

**but I still think it should be better**

Answer (score -1):

EDIT :
first convert your request in JPQL, it may look like something like that :

```
select u.name, c.college_name from User u inner join College c ON u.college_id = c.id GROUP BY u.name
```

Then construct new object, you can do (after adding all args constructor in UserQueryModel) :

```
@Query(value = "select new your.package.UserQueryModel(u.name,c.college_name) from User u inner join College c ON u.college_id = c.id GROUP BY u.name")
   List<UserQueryModel> usersWithCollege();
```

Comment: This will only work with JPQL **not** with plain SQL.

Comment: Hmm you're right, so maybe you must firstly convert request to JPQL (not native query). I think it's not a big deal.